SAS Rename External Files
I'm trying to rename some files saved in a specific folder. I also included some conditions when renaming them, like when the file name contains '214' then rename it to A; when the file name contains '217' then rename it to B, etc. Btw, all the files are XLSX.
Below is my code, I keep getting the "Error renaming:" in the log. Can someone take a look at my code and correct it for me plz? Thanks!!


%let folder = /report/Sep2024;
filename mydir "&folder.";

data _null_;
length old_name $300 new_name $300;
did = dopen('mydir'); 

if did > 0 then do;
    do i = 1 to dnum(did);

        file_name = dread(did, i);

        old_name = "&folder./" || file_name; 

        new_name = "";

        if find(file_name, '214') > 0 then new_name = "&folder./A.xlsx"; 
        else if find(file_name, '217') > 0 then new_name = "&folder./B.xlsx"; 
        else if find(file_name, '445') > 0 then new_name = "&folder./C.xlsx"; 
        else if find(file_name, '311') > 0 then new_name = "&folder./D.xlsx"; 

        if new_name ne "" then do;
            
    rc = rename("old_name","new_name",'file');
         
            if rc = 0 then put "Successfully renamed: " old_name " to " new_name;
            else put "Error renaming: " old_name " to " new_name;
        end;
    end;
    rc = dclose(did); 
end;
run;



I need to rename the external excel files saved in a specific folder under certain conditions.

You are quoting the variable names you want the value of old_name not "old_name"
rc = rename("old_name","new_name",'file');

Try
rc = rename(old_name,new_name,'file');

